# i have problem with animate function.it gives me an empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had some problem with Animate function of matplotlib.
here the code: it gives me an empty graph. maybe i need to dowload some other modules?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_data = []
y_data = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 105)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
line, = ax.plot(0, 0)


def animation_frame(i):
    x_data.append(i*10)
    y_data.append(i)

    line.set_x_data(x_data)
    line.set_y_data(y_data)
    return line,


ani = animation.FuncAnimantion(fig, func = animation_frame, frames = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01), interval = 10)
plt.show()
```

the output is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Utente\untitled0.py", line 28, in <module>
    ani = animation.FuncAnimantion (fig,func= animation_frame,frames=np.arange(0,10,0.01),interval=10)

*****AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.animation' has no attribute 'FuncAnimantion'*****
```

with an empty graph!

someone can kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few typos:

- FuncAnima**n**tion -> `FuncAnimation`
- set_x_data -> `set_xdata`
- set_y_data -> `set_ydata`

Otherwise it should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_data = []
y_data = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 105)
ax.set_ylim(0, 12)
line, = ax.plot(0, 0)


def animation_frame(i):
    x_data.append(i * 10)
    y_data.append(i)

    line.set_xdata(x_data)
    line.set_ydata(y_data)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, frames=np.arange(0, 10, 0.01), interval=10)
plt.show()
```